# How to save parsed rss to database in Android

Tags: android, xml, database, parsing, rss

Beginner here!

So I need help with saving parsed RSS feed into database to view later offline.

I am parsing RSS with SAXParser and then displaying it in ListView. 
I have managed to make working database, but I have no clue how to add parsed strings to the database. Should I to it right after parsing or after displaying ListView or something else?

My project is based on http://www.itcuties.com/android/how-to-write-android-rss-parser/  RSS parser example.

Example code would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
My main activity AsyncTask:

```
private class GetRSSDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RssItem> > {
    @Override
    protected List<RssItem> doInBackground(String... urls) {


        try {
            // Create RSS reader
            RssReader rssReader = new RssReader(urls[0]);

            // Parse RSS, get items
            return rssReader.getItems();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("RssParser", e.getMessage());
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<RssItem> result) {


        RssItem item = new RssItem();

        db.open();
        //do something by database
        db.insertNewsInfo(item);
        Log.i("String", item.toString());
        db.close();


        // Get a ListView from main view
        ListView itcItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        // Create a list adapter
        ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(local,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
        // Set list adapter for the ListView
        itcItems.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Set list view item click listener
        itcItems.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener(result, local));


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Example: To parse a news website, you can make a class `NewsInformation.java`

```
public class NewsInformation {
    public String completeTextLink;
    public String title;
    public String writerName;
    public String dateWriten;
    public String source;
    public String smallBody;
    public String bigBody;  
    public String page;
}
```

And by using the above class, insert your news to database

`DatabaseHelper.java`

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db_for_news";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 10);
    
        //fdd
        Log.i(TAG, "Object created.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE news ( page TEXT ," +
            " completeTextLink TEXT  ,title TEXT , writerName TEXT , dateWriten TEXT ," +
            " source TEXT ,  smallBody TEXT , bigBody TEXT);");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version "
            + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("Drop table if exists news" );   
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

`DatabaseHandler.java`

```
public class DatabaseHandler {

    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    //methods for all table
    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public void clearTable(String tableName) {
        database.delete( tableName, null, null);
    }

    //news table method

    public void insertNewsInfo(NewsInformation newsInfo) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("bigBody"          ,  newsInfo.bigBody );
        cv.put("completeTextLink" ,  newsInfo.completeTextLink );
        cv.put("dateWriten"       ,  newsInfo.dateWriten );
        cv.put("source"            ,  newsInfo.source );
        cv.put("smallBody"        ,  newsInfo.smallBody );
        cv.put("title"            ,  newsInfo.title );
        cv.put("writerName"       ,  newsInfo.writerName );
        cv.put("page"             ,  newsInfo.page );
    
        database.insert("news" , "writerName", cv);
    }


    public List<NewsInformation> getAllNewsForPage(String page) {   
        List<NewsInformation> NewsInfoList = new ArrayList<NewsInformation>();
     
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select completeTextLink " +
            " , title , writerName , dateWriten , source , smallBody , bigBody" +
            " FROM news where page = ?", new String[]{page});
    

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            NewsInformation newsInfo = new NewsInformation();
        
            newsInfo.completeTextLink = cursor.getString(0);
            newsInfo.title = cursor.getString(1);
            newsInfo.writerName = cursor.getString(2);
            newsInfo.dateWriten = cursor.getString(3);
            newsInfo.source = cursor.getString(4);
            newsInfo.smallBody = cursor.getString(5);
            newsInfo.bigBody = cursor.getString(6);
            newsInfo.page = page;
                
            NewsInfoList.add(newsInfo);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    
        // Make sure to close the cursor
        cursor.close();
    
        return NewsInfoList;
    }

    public String getBigBody(String completeBodyLink) {
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select bigBody FROM news where completeTextLink = ?", new String[]{completeBodyLink});
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String bigBody = cursor.getString(0);
        cursor.close();
        return bigBody;
    }       
}
```

In your Activity to save news to DataBase

```
In DATA >> private NewsDatabaseHandler    db;
In onCreate() >> db = new NewsDatabaseHandler(this);

// Where you want insert to database or read from it
db.open();

// do something by database
// for Example:
NewsInformation item = new NewsInformation();
item.completeTextLink = "Your Link of news";
item.title            = "title of news";
item.writerName       = "writer of news";
item.dataWriten       = "1999";
item.source           = "something";
item.smallBody        = "news body";
item.bigBody          = "news text";
item.page             = "1";
db.insertNewsInfo(item);
db.close();
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for thorough answer. But I cant manage to get it work somehow. I am getting lost in the main activity where I call the insert method.

Comment: Sadly, still have not managed to get it work. What to i have to put in the brackets: db.insertNewsInfo(..) ???

Comment: @Mahdi-bagvand in your getBigBody function, you need to close the cursor there as well as it will be a resource leak.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the RSS parsed successfully.  The next steps are:

1) Convert the parsed data into a java object
2) Persist the object

For step 1, if you are using the sample code from the link, you have this done already.  E.g.:

```
public class RssItem {
    // item title
    private String title;
    // item link
    private String link;
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }
    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

This java object represents the data you want to persist.  The next step is to integrate a ORM library into your project.  Generally, the most common one is [ORMlite](http://ormlite.com).  To use this:

1. Include `ormlite-android-4.47.jar` and `ormlite-core-4.47.jar` in your project in libs
2. Annotate your class [like this](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_1.html#Getting-Started)
3. Persist the items to the database

Here's an example:

```
Dao<RssItem, String> rssDao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, RssItem.class);
TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, RssItem.class);

// create an instance of RssItem
RssItem item = new RssItem();
item.setTitle("News Item A");

// persist the item object to the database
rssDao.create(item);
```

That's the basics of ORM persistence.  Once you persist them, you can query using DAO as well.